# JTemplates format Date using asp.net mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, json, date, format, jtemplate

I have the following JSON date returned from a MVC page e.g.

```
"DateProcessed":"\/Date(1258125238090)\/"
```

and I am using JTemplates to process the data as below.

```
$('#result').setTemplate($("#TemplateResultsTable").html());
$("#result").processTemplate(data);
```

This is my results template

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateResultsTable">    
<h3>{$T[0].StatusName} - Found: {$T.length} </h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date Processed</th>
    </tr>
    {#foreach $T as match}
        <tr>
            <td>{$T.match.Title}</td>
            <td>{$T.match.Description}</td>
            <td>{$T.match.DateProcessed}</td>
        </tr>
    {#/for}
</table>
</script>
```

All works great apart from the fact that my date is outputted on the page as /Date(1258125238090)/

How do I format the date inside my results template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer below in case anybody else searches this post...

Add the following JScript....

```
function formatJSONDate(jsonDate) {
    var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
    return dateFormat(date, "ddd ddS mmm yyyy");
 }
```

download a javascript [date format library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) then in your jTemplate template add

```
<td>{formatJSONDate($T.match.DateProcessed)}</td>
```

And that's that!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the answer. Just saved me some work!

Comment: @Rippo is there no way around this other than using `eval()` ?

Comment: I never found one, but to be honest I don't use JTemplates any more.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and ended up (after much aggravation) just returning the date as a string in my JSON.

Comment: Looks like I have figured it out, quite easy when you get the format right..... will post an answer soon